# How to point subfolder to asp.net web site

Tags: asp.net, iis, subdomain, subdirectory

To put it simple: I have a web site (asp.net 4 on iis 7.5), let's call it mysite.com.
I've developed my own blog, which is also an asp.net 4 web site solution (not web application).
I want search engines AND visitors to see mysite.com/blog in the address bar for the sake of SEO.

You'll find lot of posts saying a subfolder solution is to prefer for a subdomain, but none of them tells how to implement it.

One solution I found involves reverse proxy and installing the blog in eg. blog/mysite.com. This in turn requires Application Request Routing which my host (unoeuro.com) doesn't offer.

Anybody who's been through the same exercise and have a solution?

Comment: This question might be better answered on http://serverfault.com/

Comment: Could I ask a mod to move it to serverfault.com.
Thx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay. There was no easy solution, but I'm now finished with my [blog engine](http://wblogengine.net/). You can download it (with source code) for free.
It's installable as a stand-alone blog, in a subdomain and/or subfolder without any additional setup.

It's in Visual Basic by the way.